# Should Akka Actors do real processing tasks?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor, typesafe

I'm writing an application that reads relatively large text files, validates and transforms the data (every line in a text file is an own item, there are around 100M items/file) and creates some kind of output. There already exists a multihreaded Java application (using `BlockingQueue` between Reading/Processing/Persisting Tasks), but I want to implement a Scala application that does the same thing.

Akka seems to be a very popular choice for building concurrent applications. Unfortunately, due to the asynchronous nature of actors, I still don't understand what a single actor can or can't do, e.g. if I can use actors as traditional workers that do some sort of calculation.

Several documentations say that Actors should never block and I understand why. But the given examples for blocking code always only mention such things as blocking file/network IO.. things that make the actor waiting for a short period of time which is of course a bad thing.

But what if the actor is "blocking" because it actually does something useful instead of waiting? In my case, the processing and transformation of a single line/item of text takes 80ms which is quite a long time (pure processing, no IO involved). Can this work be done by an actor directly or should I use a Future instead (but then, If I have to use Futures anyway, why use Akka in the first place..)?.

The Akka docs and examples show that work can be done directly by actors. But it seems that the authors only do very simplistic work (such as calling filter on a String or incrementing a counter and that's it). I don't know if they do this to keep the docs simple and concise or because you really should not do more that within an actor.

How would you design an Akka-based application for my use case (reading text file, processing every line which takes quite some time, eventually persisting the result)? Or is this some kind of problem that does not suit to Akka?

Comment: blocking a `Future` inside common thread-pool isn't recommended as well as it also causes thread starvation. 80ms for real calculations is fine as it is more-less stable value, you steel can use CPU in full power

Comment: you may also consider splitting your computation into smaller pieces and delegate the pieces to other actors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It all depends on the type of an actor.

I use this rule of thumb: if you don't need to talk to this actor and this actor does not have any other responsibilities, then it's ok to block in it doing actual work. You can treat it as a `Future` and this is what I would call a "worker".

If you block in an actor that is not a leaf node (worker), i.e. work distributor then the whole system will slow down.

There are a few patterns that involve work pulling/pushing or actor per request model. Either of those could be a fit for your application. You can have a manager that creates an actor for each piece of work and when the work is finished actor sends result back to manager and dies. You can also keep an actor alive and ask for more work from that actor. You can also combine actors and Futures.

Sometimes you want to be able to talk to a worker if your processing is more complex and involves multiple stages. In that case a worker can delegate work yet to another actor or to a future.

To sum-up don't block in manager/work distribution actors. It's ok to block in workers if that does not slow your system down.

disclaimer: by blocking I mean doing actual work, not just busy waiting which is never ok.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense to me. However, I wonder if it isn't crucial to know how many underlying threads are involved. Image you have a very responsive actor that distributes all the work and doesn't block at all. Then there is a "worker actor" that receives work and blocks for a certain amount of time doing the job. At a first glance, this scenario seems to be okay. But what if both actors run on the same thread? Wouldn't the worker actor still slow down the distribution actor as long as there is work to do? And if yes, is this something that can be controlled ?

Comment: You can have separate thread pools aka execution contexts for separate groups of actors: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html

Answer (score 3):

Doing computations that take 100ms is fine in an actor. However, you need to make sure to properly deal with backpressure. One way would be to use the [work-pulling pattern](http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern/), where your CPU bound actors request new work whenever they are ready instead of receiving new work items in a message.

That said, your problem description sounds like a processing pipeline that might benefit from using a higher level abstraction such as [akka streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0/scala.html?_ga=1.3563568.1402611546.1442228996). Basically, produce a stream of file names to be processed and then use transformations such as map to get the desired result. I have something like this in production that sounds pretty similar to your problem description, and it works very well provided the data used by the individual processing chunks is not too large.

Of course, a stream will also be materialized to a number of actors. But the high level interface will be more type-safe and easier to reason about.